# ExecuteMany inserting wrong values in NUMBER column: too large values instead of actual value

Tags: javascript, oracle, bulkinsert, node-oracledb, executemany

I am doing bulk insertion using executeMany in node-oracle db. It executes successfully , but the Numbers with decimal points are being inserted as a false very large value ...

Actual values are **for eg. 102.22, 456672.89** but they are being inserted as shown in image below: AMOUNT is a NUMBER column. This is happening only for numbers containing decimals. Numbers without decimals are inserting fine

[image]

[image]

Also, in binds, i am passing field as Number.

[image]

When i logged binds before query execution, the values were fine .. but they inserted as a very large number.
why is this happening? .. Is this a Javascript issue or node-oracle db's ExecuteMany issue?

Comment: Are you sure you're putting the right values in the right columns? Those look like they could be account numbers, or similar (too long for card number, unless you're storing CVV with it *8-). Check the column list in the insert statement against the bind array field order.

Comment: this kind of value does not exist in the entire instructions that i am inserting. I know this is a very weird issue. @AlexPoole

Comment: Also i checked entire logs, binds associated with query. Nothing like this exists

Comment: This question was cross posted to https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1346